# How magento knows which store use?

Tags: magento

When does Magento decide which store view to use, and when is the current locale set?

I am trying to know where should I go in file to know that which store view will used in fronend?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks everybody,

I want to share of my findings:

1. Index.php calls `Mage::run()`
2. It calls app/mage.php :: run()
3. run function has  `self::$_app->run(...)` line of code which ultimatately calls `Mage_Core_Model_App::run()` function
4. `Mage_Core_Model_App::run()` includes `$this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);`
5. `_initCurrentStore()` :: Loads all websites, group and stores into website, group and store object using `_initStores()` method. this function checks whether the site is website or  store group or store, if it is one these then there it sets current store. If scope is base, then it goes through `$this->_checkCookieStore()`
6. `$this->_checkCookieStore()` :: this gets the store type from cookie `$this->getCookie()->get(Mage_Core_Model_Store::COOKIE_NAME);`,  there it checks whether it is website, group or store and set current store in `$this->_currentStore = $store;`  on the base of value returned by cookie.
7. `Mage_Core_Model_App::_checkGetStore()`, this checks current store with the xpath_of_store_url , updates cookie

Current locale is set when `Mage_Core_Model_App::init()` is called , init() function has `$this->_initEnvironment();` which has  a setting of locale

Comment: `$this->_initEnvironment(); which has a setting of locale` This seems to be incorrect. The reference to `locale` you are talking about is in here: `date_default_timezone_set(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);` which sets it to UTC time. It must be further along in the application's store initialization that current locale for the client's request is set.

Answer (score 2):

If "Add Store Code to Urls" setting is set, then 
Magento is also detecting store based on the store code presence in the url.
e.g. domain.com/en/
It is implemented in Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http::setPathInfo()

So in order of priority (lowest wins) Magento uses following data to detect store:

1. check if url contains store code -> use it
2. check if cookie with store is set
3. use $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']  and $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']
4. get default store from default store group, and default store group 
   from default website

Answer (score 1):

I am studying for the magento certifcation exam too and I am not 100% sure about the response for the locale. My searches on the web demonstrates that the widely accepted answer is:

Current locale is set when Mage_Core_Model_App::init() is called , init() function has $this->_initEnvironment(); which has a setting of locale

Seems like someone someone said that and every body is just copying that but Im not sure it is right. See the locale is decided in Mage_Core_Model_Locale::__construct() but this construct is not called in $this->_initEnvironment() because in this method the Mage_Core_Model_Locale is only used as a static class. So this should not get the construct to run:

```
protected function _initEnvironment()
{
    $this->setErrorHandler(self::DEFAULT_ERROR_HANDLER);
    date_default_timezone_set(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);
    return $this;
}
```

It seems that this function only uses the constants from the Mage_Core_Model_Locale in order to set the timezone. Timezone is not the same as locale.

However in Mage_Core_Model_App the function getLocale() does instantiate the locale properly which should get the constructor to be run and therefore the Mage_Core_Model_Locale::setLocale to run.

Mage_Core_Model_App

```
public function getLocale()
{
    if (!$this->_locale) {
        $this->_locale = Mage::getSingleton('core/locale');
    }
    return $this->_locale;
}
```

Mage_Core_Model_Locale

```
public function __construct($locale = null)
{
    $this->setLocale($locale);
}

public function setLocale($locale = null)
{
    if (($locale !== null) && is_string($locale)) {
        $this->_localeCode = $locale;
    } else {
        $this->_localeCode = $this->getDefaultLocale();
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_locale_set_locale', array('locale'=>$this));
    return $this;
}
```

edit:

While I'm at it I decided to go right ahead and verify if I was right or not. To do this I added

```
mageDebugBacktrace(); die();
```

to the setLocale() method of the Mage Core Locale model.
This method is when the Locale model sets the value on its _localeCode property. In other words this is when the locale gets set. The backtrace will show us the calling chain of methods that led to it.

The result was this:

```
[1] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php:94
[2] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348
[3] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php:463
[4] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php:477
[5] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:1018
[6] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php:347
[7] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php:179
[8] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php:119
[9] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php:146
[10] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php:121
[11] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App/Area.php:93
[12] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:774
[13] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:512
[14] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php:64
[15] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:407
[16] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:250
[17] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:172
[18] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[19] /var/www/magento/htdocs/app/Mage.php:684
[20] /var/www/magento/htdocs/index.php:87
```

You can see line 18 App model line 354 is this code:

```
$this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
```

This is in the App model run() method. the whole method looks like this:

```
public function run($params)
    {
        $options = isset($params['options']) ? $params['options'] : array();
        $this->baseInit($options);
        Mage::register('application_params', $params);

        if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
            $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        } else {
            $this->_initModules();
            $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

            if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
                $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
                $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
                $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
                $this->_initRequest();
                Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
            }

            $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

So the whole idea that the locale is set in _initEnvironment() which is called at the beginning of baseInit() is incorrect. Maybe someone got confused and did not know the difference between "default timezone" and "locale" but its definitely not the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

To get current store details use the below code.

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$name = $store->getName();
```